# transitioning from one scene to another swift

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/027rJ.jpg)

This is my current swift code in Xcode. I have 2 problems, the first one being unable to control-drag the textfield to the code. The second one is how to transition from the first scene to the second scene.

first scene is the access_code one,
the second is the map view.

I want to be able to have the user enter an access code in the text field, and when they hit return. the program will change the view to the map view. (the user will get different maps based on the code they enter).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, I see that on the right side you have manual UIViewController set.
If the UIViewController on the right is not matching scene to the right it will not work. (You can't drag text field to the code.) It is very hard to say what is wrong but this could be a clue.

Second think is transition between two scenes.

You will need to create segue between those two screens. You dreg from first UIViewController to another in  storyboard and give this seque the identifier.

Then in code, inside method where return key is pressed, call

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "myIdentifireSetInStoryboard", sender: self)
```

To get method that is called when return key is pressed, look into UITextfieldDelegate method textFieldDidEndEditing...

I hope it help.